# Currency data type necessary in financial applications?

Tags: java, jpa, currency, finance

We're developing a stock trading application and debating whether we should introduce a data type for currency.

The proposed `Currency` data type contains an amount and a type of currency(e.g. USD, EUR, JPY).

I'm against it at this point because we'd use it for a property type of persistent beans as well.

First, it'd contain redudant data. Take a `StockQuote` class for example that contains OHLC(open, high, low, and close prices) of a given stock. If each of them were to be represented by a `Currency` instance, then all of OHLC would have references to the same currency type(e.g USD). In financial applications, currency values are used all over the place, not just stock quotes, so we're talking about lots of redundancy.

Second, a `Currency` instance is a combination of two values(amount and type of currency), so you'd either drop the type of currency altogether and store only the amount field in the database table or create a currency type column in the table for each `Currency` property, which would be redundant within the table and break the 2nd normal form. Either way, reading a record from the table back into a `StockQuote` object would be impossible with JPA and tricky at best with Hibernate.

Anyone faced similar problems before? Is it normal for financial applications to have a custom currency class? If so, how did you implement it with JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: Use java.math.BigDecimal or perhaps derive your own class based on it (use composition not inheritance), but no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that stocks are not always quoted in plain currencies. e.g. Stocks on the LSE are quoted in pence, not pounds.  All stocks on an exchange will be quotes in the same currency units so you can assume that for a given stock on a given exchange, you know what the currency is, making the currency redundant. All you need is the price.

Answer (score 1):

The Currency entity models the world correctly, there is no going around it.

Your argument about StockQuote is not really a strong one, you can easily reduce it to 1 times currency type and 4 times a long integer.

Update:

```
@Entity
public StockQuote {
     private java.util.Currency currency; // find a nice database mapping of this, or use a ISO 4217 String instead
     private long open;
     private long close;
     private long high;
     private long low;

}
```

seems to be sufficient for a good database mapping. Of course, if you make utility methods like

```
MyCurrencyAmount currency = StockQuote.getOpenAsMyCurrencyAmount();
```

then most of any overhead would be solved. But note that you need both the java.util.Currency (being without an amount) and your own CurrencyAmount (or whatever), being with the java.util.Currency and an amount.

Comment: Are you suggesting a custom class that combines a java.util.Currency field and a double field wouldn't be necessary then?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a `double` field for currency/money but `BigDecimal`

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman, I guess you are refering not to BigDecimal but BigInteger? Well I'd go with the native types integer (no comma!) any day. So do not model dollars, model cent.

Comment: I think you can make assumptions about the range a stock quote can be, if 2 billion per stock (int) is not a safe limit then 9 billion billion (long) should be.  This is more than all the dollars and euros in the world so one stock is unlikely to cost more than this. ;)

Comment: Its worth remembering that prices are still manually entered alot of the time.  A trader is not going to manually enter an 18+ digit number as a price.

Comment: Even with hyper-inflation, the underlying unit would change. There is no point entering an 18 digit number as the 6th digit will change before you have had a chance to enter it.  There are practical considerations which limit the number of digits a stock can have. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd normal form is not a "holy grail".

Sometimes it's better to break it.
You are working with a finance application. It's important to have the same pricing to work with. If all data in your database has the same currency, then yes, it is not needed.

But if you use different currencies, then you must store the type of currency for each money value. You can't avoid it. If you do, then you could end up calculating with USD, while the original value was with currency BP or EUR. That will give very different values.

By the way: Java has it's own class: `java.util.Currency`

Comment: True, but java.util.Currency doesn't have an amount field, so a custom class would have that class plus the amount field.